# How to populate Objective C tableview with this JSON data

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, tableview

I am very new to programming in Objective C (as in a few days), and unfortunately have an iPhone app due as a project for a class in a few days (in retrospect I probably should have chosen something different). One of the main features my app needs is the ability to select a dish from a menu by first selecting the meal on one page, and then the category on the next page, and then the dish on the final page. I have gotten my app to download a JSON file from an internet API and store it as an NSArray variable, but now I need to use that array to populate my tableview. Below is a sample from the downloaded array from my app's debug window. I already have the basic framework of the app (i.e. several different views) in place. This came from a sample app that populates the tableview rows with data from a plist file, but I want to use this JSON data. How would I use this array to populate the rows with the JSON data stored in this NSArray variable?
Thanks!

```
2012-12-05 03:29:48.973 MLBMobile[3858:c07] {
    category = "BREAKFAST MEATS";
    date = "2012-12-05";
    meal = BREAKFAST;
    name = "Low-Sodium Ham";
    portion = 1;
    recipe = 319044;
    unit = oz;
}
2012-12-05 03:29:48.975 MLBMobile[3858:c07] {
    category = "BREAKFAST MEATS";
    date = "2012-12-05";
    meal = BREAKFAST;
    name = "Roasted Low-Sodium Turkey";
    portion = 4;
    recipe = 113503;
    unit = oz;
}
2012-12-05 03:29:48.976 MLBMobile[3858:c07] {
    category = "BREAKFAST ENTREES";
    date = "2012-12-05";
    meal = BREAKFAST;
    name = "Cheddar Cheese";
    portion = 1;
    recipe = 130029;
    unit = oz;
}
2012-12-05 03:29:48.976 MLBMobile[3858:c07] {
    category = "BREAKFAST ENTREES";
    date = "2012-12-05";
    meal = BREAKFAST;
    name = "Hard Cooked Eggs - Cage Free";
    portion = 1;
    recipe = 061009;
    unit = each;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your array variable you can iterate through each element. Use fast enumeration:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in yourArrayVariable){
    NSString *category = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    //...you get the point
}
```

Now you can populate your row by just setting the properties of the row. For example, if you are using the default [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
cell.textLabel.text = name;
```

There is a bit more to this that you can do for better data/model/view separation, but I have just included examples as if it were all done locally in one file.

Comment: Thanks! I am seeing the meal categories in my debug window, but I am getting the meal category for each dish (so my list looks like BREAKFAST BREAKFAST BREAKFAST BREAKFAST etc.) How would I go about only setting one row for each unique meal category?

Comment: You can have a separate hash table (NSMutableDictionary) that keeps track of categories that have been displayed, so, once you set, you can insert a key into the hash table. Upon every insert, check if it exists in the hash table, if not, then skip over it. Please consider marking this answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks! I did basically that and got it working (at least the first view).